# Progress Bar when loading JQuery Data

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

i create some simple tracking application that loads data from database using Jquery AJAX,   i need some progress bar that shows user, the data is loaded.

I've two functions here;

```
     function showResult(){
            valobj = $('#search_box').val();
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#bc_result").show("slow");
                $("#result-table").show().html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4>Error!</h4>Please insert your  Number... </div>");
            } else {
                $.get("ex.php", { bl : valobj }, function(data,status){
                    //getting value to components 
                    $("#result-table").show().html(data);
                    $("#title_search_result").show();
                    $("#bc_result").show("slow");      
                });
            } //end if value empty
        }
```

and

```
function progressResult(){
          var progress = setInterval(function() {
          var $bar = $('.bar');

          if ($bar.width()==680) {
             clearInterval(progress);
             $('.progress').removeClass('active');
           } else {
             $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
           }
         }, 800);
       }
```

how to combine these two method so, when user clicks the button progress bar will working,after completed shows the result?

anyway, the result from the php file is a table that placed inside the div

```
<div id="result-table"></div>
```

how to combine that two function ? thanks.

**UPDATE**

i place some function to remove progress bar after showing the result

```
    function progressResult(){
          var progress = setInterval(function() {
          var $bar = $('.bar');

          if ($bar.width()==680) {
             clearInterval(progress);
             $('.progress').removeClass('active');
           } else {
             $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
           }
         }, 800);
       }

       function removeProgressResult(){
           $('.bar').hide();
           $('.progress').hide();
       }

       function showResult(){
            valobj = $('#search_box').val();
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#bc_result").show("slow");
                $("#result-table").show().html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4>Error!</h4>Please insert your BL Number... </div>");
            } else {
                progressResult();
                $.get("ex.php", { bl : valobj }, function(data,status){
                    alert(status);
                    if(status == "success"){
                        //getting value to components 
                        $("#result-table").show().html(data);
                        $("#title_search_result").show();
                        $("#bc_result").show("slow");
                        //removeProgressResult();
                    } 
                });
            } //end if value empty
        }
```

the showResult function is calling progressREsult(), but instead showing the result, the progress bar and the result is coming together.

how to resolve that?

Comment: @jgauffin, i'm sorry to bother you, i saw your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690417/bootstrap-page-load-progress-bar-animation

perhaps, if you have time, can you help me? thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Your **fist function** has to change

so that you will call the progressResult() has to call when ever the showResult() get called
dont show the result when ever the ajax return, lets wait untill the progressResult() finish the job

you have to change the **second function** so that
you have to display the result after the unction get finished

```
function showResult(){
            valobj = $('#search_box').val();
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#bc_result").show("slow");
                $("#result-table").show().html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4>Error!</h4>Please insert your  Number... </div>");
            } else {

                progressResult();

                $.get("ex.php", { bl : valobj }, function(data,status){
                    //getting value to components 
                    $("#result-table").html(data);
                    $("#title_search_result").show();
                    $("#bc_result").show("slow");      
                });
            } //end if value empty
        }



function progressResult(){
          var progress = setInterval(function() {
          var $bar = $('.bar');

          if ($bar.width()==680) {
             clearInterval(progress);

             $("#result-table").show();


             $('.progress').removeClass('active');
           } else {
             $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
           }
         }, 800);
       }
```

you should be very careful to finish the progress bar only after ajax get the result

Comment: hi, the function progressResult() is coming together with the showResult() function, not waiting after the progress bar reach the limit.

Comment: u mean progressbar and result are coming togather, result is not waiting for the progressbar to finish the progress